# Typoscript | How to write this like an IF ELSE condition?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I'm new to Typo3, and building a site with TemplaVoila.
I got the following TS (within TV XML) which outputs 2 sets of content

```
10= RECORDS
10.source.current=1
10.tables = tt_content
10.wrap.required = 1
10.wrap = <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--> | <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->]]>

20 = CONTENT
20.table = tt_content
20.select {
  pidInList = 36
}
```

The first set (10) is the current page content, and the second (20) fetches content from page ID 36.
Currently both are printed, but I want 20 to print only if 10 is empty.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
  table = tt_content
  select.pidInList = 36
}
```

did not test, but should work. stdWrap is executed after wrap. So in this case, you will not have the Search-Markers are set.

Comment: Awesome dude :D Works like a charm.